# Matching group of words

Tags: python

I want to find words that are in my dictionary and see if they are in the text that I have taken as input.

For example my dictionary is:

```javascript
{ 'excited': 3, 'does not work': -2, 'didnt like': -3,'like' : 3}
```

My text is:

```
The restaurant was awesome. I was really excited to eat octopus, but i didn't like
shrimps served there.
```

The problem is, as I am reading word by word of the text, it's easy to read words like 'excited' and find it in the dictionary, but how do i match a group of words like 'didn't like'?
My code looks like this:

```python
text= 'The restaurant was awesome. I was really excited to eat octopus, but i 
didnt like shrimps served there.'
words= text.split()
dict= { 'excited': 3, 'does not work': -2, 'didnt like': -3,'like' : 3}
for word in words:
    if dict.has_key(word):
        print word
```

Comment: Did you tried to make any attempt?

Comment: Then you need to show your attempt to us as that would help us to identify your problem and also encourage others to help you :)

Comment: Try looking up some information on bigrams (2 words), trigrams (3 words), or generally n-grams (n words). You might also want to check lemmatisation, so i.e. words like "excite", "exciting" or "excited" count as the same word. I guess NLTK would be a good starting point (http://www.nltk.org).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.count` and a for loop.

```
d = {'excited': 3, 'does not work': -2, 'didnt like': -3, 'like' : 3}
result_dict = dict.fromkeys(d, 0)
for word in d.keys()
    result_dict[word] = text.count(word)
```

Faster might be using regex.

```
d = {'excited': 3, 'does not work': -2, 'didnt like': -3, 'like' : 3}
pat = re.compile("("+"|".join([re.escape(key) for key in sorted(d, key=len, reverse=True)])+")")
results = pat.findall(text)
# ['excited', 'like']
```

Comment: The second is close... couple of suggestions - pre-generate the keys in descending order of length to make sure you get longest runs first `keys = sorted(d, key=len, reverse=True)`... (as `dict`s are arbitarily ordered, `like` might appear before `dont like` in your pattern). Build the pattern as a single group, eg: `pat = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(re.escape(key) for key in keys) + ')')` - then when you do the `re.findall(text)` you'll get a flat list instead of a list of tuples `['excited', 'didnt like']`

Comment: @JonClements I like it! Though in this case it wouldn't matter if it came up `like|don't like` or the other way around, it WOULD matter if it came up `upset|upset we had to leave` :). Is `re.findall` smart enough to return the flat list in that case? I thought I'd just get a list with a single item (the last match found) but I don't have the time to test it atm